# Android login/registration with shared preferences

Tags: android, session, authentication, sharedpreferences, user-registration

I'm new to Android. I'm doing an app for an university exam. I have to do an application for a travel agency. I'd like to manage the user session with shared preferences in order to save basic information and the eventually travels that the user booked. I can't find an example on the web that combine the registration and login forms. I wrote this code but it's not working. It doesn't show any error. I think what I wrote it's not logic. I'd like to register first and login with the information I gave in the registration form. Thank you for your help.

This is my Login.java:

```
package com.example.trip;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

public static android.content.SharedPreferences SharedPreferences = null;

private static final String PREFER_NAME = null;

Button buttonLogin;

EditText txtUsername, txtPassword;

// User Session Manager Class
UserSession session;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login); 

    Button switchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);
    switchButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this, Reg.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    // User Session Manager
    session = new UserSession(getApplicationContext());                

    // get Email, Password input text
    txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword); 

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "User Login Status: " + session.isUserLoggedIn(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    // User Login button
    buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    // Login button click event
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Get username, password from EditText
            String username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

            // Validate if username, password is filled             
            if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){

                if (SharedPreferences.contains("name"))
                  {
                     String uName = (SharedPreferences).getString("name", "");

                  }

                  if (SharedPreferences.contains("email"))
                  {
                     String uEmail = (SharedPreferences).getString("email", "");

                  }

                            Object uName = null;
                            Object uEmail = null;
                            if(username.equals(uName) && password.equals(uEmail)){

                                session.createUserLoginSession(uName, 
                                   uEmail);

                                // Starting MainActivity
                                Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(i);

                                finish();

                            }else{

                                // username / password doesn't match&
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                  "Username/Password is incorrect",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }               
                        }else{

                            // user didn't entered username or password
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                 "Please enter username and password",
                                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    }
                });
}
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.MENU_1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            this.startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.MENU_2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent2);
        break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }       
}
```

This is the UserSession.java:

```
package com.example.trip;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class UserSession {
// Shared Preferences reference
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor reference for Shared preferences
Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared preferences mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Shared preferences file name
public static final String PREFER_NAME = "AndroidExamplePref";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
public static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";

// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

// Constructor
public UserSession(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

//Create login session
public void createUserLoginSession(Object uName, Object uEmail){
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing name in preferences
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, (String) uName);

    // Storing email in preferences
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, (String) uEmail);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}   

/**
 * Check login method will check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else do anything
 * */
public boolean checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isUserLoggedIn()){

        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);

        // Closing all the Activities from stack
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



/**
 * Get stored session data
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){

    //Use hashmap to store user credentials
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // user name
    user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

    // user email id
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Clear session details
 * */
public void logoutUser(){

    // Clearing all user data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // After logout redirect user to MainActivity
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);

    // Closing all the Activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Staring Login Activity
    _context.startActivity(i);
}


// Check for login
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, false);
}
}
```

This is the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.MENU_1:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        this.startActivity(intent1);
        break;
    case R.id.MENU_2:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent2);
    break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

This is my Reg.java:

```
package com.example.trip;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Reg extends ActionBarActivity {

SharedPreferences SharedPreferences;
Editor editor;
Button buttonReg2;
EditText txtUsername, txtPassword, txtEmail;  
UserSession session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reg);

txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
buttonReg2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReg2);

// creating an shared Preference file for the information to be stored
// first argument is the name of file and second is the mode, 0 is private mode

SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Reg", 0);
// get editor to edit in file
editor = SharedPreferences.edit();

buttonReg2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick (View v) {
    String name = txtUsername.getText().toString();
    String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
    String pass = txtPassword.getText().toString();

    if(txtUsername.getText().length()<=0){
        Toast.makeText(Reg.this, "Enter name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if( txtEmail.getText().length()<=0){
        Toast.makeText(Reg.this, "Enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if( txtPassword.getText().length()<=0){
        Toast.makeText(Reg.this, "Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{

    // as now we have information in string. Lets stored them with the help of editor
    editor.putString("Name", name);
    editor.putString("Email",email);
    editor.putString("txtPassword",pass);
    editor.commit();}   // commit the values

    // after saving the value open next activity
    Intent ob = new Intent(Reg.this, Login.class);
    startActivity(ob);

    }
});
}

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.MENU_1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            this.startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.MENU_2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent2);
        break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }
 }
```

The XML code of the MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/destinazione" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/checkin" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="date" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/checkout" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="date" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/viaggiatori" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/stelle" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:entries="@array/stelle"/>
    </TableRow>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFind"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonFind" />

  </TableLayout>
```

The XML code for the login form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="top"
android:shrinkColumns="0"
android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/txtUsername" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/txtPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </TableRow>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonLogin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonReg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonReg" />

 </TableLayout>
```

This is the XML code for the registration form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="top"
android:shrinkColumns="0"
android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/Email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/txtPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </TableRow>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonReg2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttonReg2" />

 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Does your application connect to server?

Comment: No, I prefer to do without server if it's possible.

Comment: If you want to make registration without server side, i dont think anything wrong with code example that you provided.

Comment: You can have separate forms for login and registration, so after registration login form will appear and compare values of local saved registration data with form data

Comment: Instead you should have used SQLite Database for storing the user details. And then manage session using SharedPreference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is working code, try it.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.menu1:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        this.startActivity(intent1);
        break;
    case R.id.menu2:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent2);
    break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

**Reg.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Reg extends ActionBarActivity {

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
Editor editor;
Button buttonReg2;
EditText txtUsername, txtPassword, txtEmail;  
UserSession session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reg);

txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
buttonReg2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReg2);

// creating an shared Preference file for the information to be stored
// first argument is the name of file and second is the mode, 0 is private mode

sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Reg", 0);
// get editor to edit in file
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

buttonReg2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick (View v) {
    String name = txtUsername.getText().toString();
    String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
    String pass = txtPassword.getText().toString();

    if(txtUsername.getText().length()<=0){
        Toast.makeText(Reg.this, "Enter name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if( txtEmail.getText().length()<=0){
        Toast.makeText(Reg.this, "Enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if( txtPassword.getText().length()<=0){
        Toast.makeText(Reg.this, "Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{

    // as now we have information in string. Lets stored them with the help of editor
    editor.putString("Name", name);
    editor.putString("Email",email);
    editor.putString("txtPassword",pass);
    editor.commit();}   // commit the values

    // after saving the value open next activity
    Intent ob = new Intent(Reg.this, Login.class);
    startActivity(ob);

    }
});
}

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            this.startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.menu2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent2);
        break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }
 }
```

**Login.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

//public static android.content.SharedPreferences SharedPreferences = null;

private static final String PREFER_NAME = "Reg";

Button buttonLogin;

EditText txtUsername, txtPassword;

// User Session Manager Class
UserSession session;

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login); 

    Button switchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonReg);
    switchButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this, Reg.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    // User Session Manager
    session = new UserSession(getApplicationContext());                

    // get Email, Password input text
    txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword); 

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "User Login Status: " + session.isUserLoggedIn(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    // User Login button
    buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    // Login button click event
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Get username, password from EditText
            String username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

            // Validate if username, password is filled             
            if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){
                    String uName = null;
                    String uPassword =null;

                if (sharedPreferences.contains("Name"))
                  {
                     uName = sharedPreferences.getString("Name", "");

                  }

                  if (sharedPreferences.contains("txtPassword"))
                  {
                     uPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("txtPassword", "");

                  }

                           // Object uName = null;
                           // Object uEmail = null;
                            if(username.equals(uName) && password.equals(uPassword)){

                                session.createUserLoginSession(uName, 
                                   uPassword);

                                // Starting MainActivity
                                Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(i);

                                finish();

                            }else{

                                // username / password doesn't match&
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                  "Username/Password is incorrect",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }               
                        }else{

                            // user didn't entered username or password
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                 "Please enter username and password",
                                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    }
                });
}
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.menu1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            this.startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.menu2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent2);
        break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }       
}
```

**UserSession.java**

```
package com.example.tripmanager;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class UserSession {
// Shared Preferences reference
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor reference for Shared preferences
Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared preferences mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Shared preferences file name
public static final String PREFER_NAME = "Reg";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
public static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";

// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";

// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";

// password
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "txtPassword";

// Constructor
public UserSession(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

//Create login session
public void createUserLoginSession(String uName, String uPassword){
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing name in preferences
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, uName);

    // Storing email in preferences
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL,  uPassword);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}   

/**
 * Check login method will check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else do anything
 * */
public boolean checkLogin(){
    // Check login status
    if(!this.isUserLoggedIn()){

        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);

        // Closing all the Activities from stack
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



/**
 * Get stored session data
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){

    //Use hashmap to store user credentials
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // user name
    user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

    // user email id
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Clear session details
 * */
public void logoutUser(){

    // Clearing all user data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // After logout redirect user to MainActivity
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);

    // Closing all the Activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Staring Login Activity
    _context.startActivity(i);
}


// Check for login
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, false);
}
}
```

Comment: I edit the question I did. I made the changes you write me but it still doesn't working.

Comment: Login.jadva, Line 19 : private static final String PREFER_NAME = "AndroidExamplePref";

Comment: Still not working. When I touch the button 'Register me' nothing happen!

Comment: I put "public static final" instead of private and after the registration it opens the login form, but the login doesn't recognize username and password.

Comment: edited the answer: be careful about using object name! its start with lower case letter 's', not 'S'.

Comment: yes, i named it Reg, but i don't know where i have to use that name in usersession.java and login.java

Comment: the variable names are also different: using "Name" to gegister sharedpreference, but using "name" to retrieve. and the same for email. do u wnt to compare the three parameters forlogin?

Comment: I'd like to register with name, email and password and then login with only name and password.

Comment: working code added for your reference, try it, its tested, if you get any error plese put it over here.

Comment: Thank you! It's working. Where can I see the saved data? And how can I manage unique session? I don't want two users with the same name and email..

Answer (score 3):

This code working in my project,must try it

Use this code after login validation to store login value

```
  String Username = textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String Password = textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString();
        final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Registered", true);
        editor.putString("Username", Username);
        editor.putString("Password", Password);
        editor.apply();
```

Create new empty activity and copy this code

```
  Boolean Registered;
    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Registered = sharedPref.getBoolean("Registered", false);

    if (!Registered)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Splash.class));
    }else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    }
```

In Menifest file copy the intent-filter code in newly created empty file for initial access.

For Logout, Create any button copy this code in click on listener

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you haven't called the checkLogin() function you have created in the UserSession.java class into the Login.java. Bcz of which the login status is not being checked.
Add this in your Login.java:

```
if(session.checkLogin()){
        val i=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
    }
    else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
```

And this to your UserSession class as an else statement to the if(!isUserLoggedIn):

```
else {
       val i1=Intent(_context, MainActivity::class.java)
       _context.startActivity(i1)
     }
```

Then return false as you did before.

**This code is in Kotlin**