# Login session-Shared preference

Tags: java, php, android, session

I am able to use shared preference. I can store and retrieve the data from shared preference folder. But I am not able to set back shared preference to null while logout. Please guide me how to maintain the session in Login.

LoginActivity.Java:- 
Here I am handling the login form.. After comparing the email id and password the data is stored in shared preference.And I am able to retrieve the data as well. But how to maintain the session?

```
package com.kezinking.nupur.kezinking;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Space;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import static android.R.attr.password;

/**
 * Created by Nupur on 8/2/2016.
 */

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String MY_JSON = "MY_JSON";
    private static final String JSON_URL = "http://kezinking.com/AndroidLogin";

    EditText input_email, input_password;
    Button btn_login, btnContactUs, btnWorkhr, btnDeltime, btnMoneyBack;
    TextView link_signup, textViewJSON, txtcheck,value;
    private static Boolean flag = false;
   public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    public static final String Phone = "phoneKey";
    public static final String emailkey = "emailKey";
    public static final String UserId = "user_id";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        link_signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_signup);
        input_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        input_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        textViewJSON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewJSON);
        // value=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.value);
        txtcheck = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcheck);
        value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);
//shared preference folder
  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //onClick Event on login Button
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login();
            }
        });
        link_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                LoginActivity.this.getIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void login() {
        if (!validate()) {
            onLoginFailed();
            return;
        } else {
            getJSON(JSON_URL);
        }
    }

    public void getJSON(String url) {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "Please Wait...", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String uri = params[0];

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    //String result=null;
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                textViewJSON.setText(s);
                String jsonString = textViewJSON.getText().toString();

                String email = input_email.getText().toString();
                String password = input_password.getText().toString();
              /**  md5(password); // Enrcypting the given password **/




                // final String myResult = (email) + (password);
              //  String value = (String.valueOf(email + password));

               // System.out.println(value);
                // String value=(input_email.getText().toString()+input_password.getText().toString());
                //String input_email = "";
                //String input_password = "";
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                    //System.out.println("result " + result);
                    //iterate through json array and check if id is same with your search

                    //System.out.println("length " + result.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                       // System.out.println(i);
                        JSONObject item = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String Email = item.getString("email");
                        String Password = item.getString("password");
                        //System.out.println("Email from json "+ Email);
                        //System.out.println("Password from json " + Password);
                        if (Email.equals(email) && Password.equals(password)) {
                            //System.out.println("Email from json"+ Email);
                           // System.out.println("Password from json" + Password);
                         String username=item.getString("username");
                            String userid=item.getString("user_id");

                            String phone_number=item.getString("con_no");
                            String emailSaved = item.getString("email");
                       //  System.out.println("Email from json "+ Email);
                          //  System.out.println("Password from json " + Password);
                         //   System.out.println("username from json " + username);
                          //  System.out.println("userid from json " + userid);
                        //    System.out.println("phone_number from json " + phone_number);

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
// Store data in shared preference
                            editor.putString(Name, username);
                            editor.putString(Phone, phone_number);
                            editor.putString(UserId,userid);
                            editor.putString(emailkey, emailSaved);
                            editor.commit();

                            flag=true;
// Retrieve data from shared Preference folder
                            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

                            String show_name = prefs.getString("Name", username); // getting data-name from shared preference
                            String show_email=prefs.getString("emailkey", emailSaved); // retrieving data from shared preference folder
// Checking the values are coming correct from shared preference folder or not
                            System.out.println("Shared_preference-email " + show_email);
                            System.out.println("Shared_preference-username " + show_name);
                           // value.setText(restoredText);

                            onLoginSuccess();


                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!flag){
                        onLoginFailed();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

//here you can show the result
                Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "email = " + email);
                Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "password = " + password);


            }
        }


        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute(url);

    }
 /**   private String md5(String password) {
        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.reset();
            digest.update(password.getBytes());
            byte[] a = digest.digest();
            int len = a.length;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));
                sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        { e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.print(password);
       return password;


    } **/


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // disable going back to the MainActivity
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    public void onLoginSuccess() {
        btn_login.setEnabled(true);
        if(sharedpreferences!=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            LoginActivity.this.getIntent();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Shared preference is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }




        // finish();
    }


    public void onLoginFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // btn_login.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;

        String email = input_email.getText().toString();
        String password = input_password.getText().toString();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            input_email.setError("enter a valid email address");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            input_email.setError(null);
        }

        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            input_password.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            input_password.setError(null);
        }

        return valid;
    }

}
```

The shared preference  sharedpreferences is global variable So I can use this variable in other java classes too ? I want to use this in logout java class. How can I use it in other java classes?

And how can I set my username and email to some textview. 
For example if my textview is show_customername. Then I want to set  show_customername.setText(show_name); . 
I tried doing like this:-

```
show_customername.setText(show_name);
```

But this is not working.
Please guide me in maintaining the login session. Thanks in advance. Hope my question will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Store a **boolean value** in your shared preferences. **Make it true** when you are successfully logged in and for next time before sending intent for Login Activity **check whether that boolean value is true or false**.If true skip login screen else show login screen. If ou have logout option in your app then set boolean value to false and save it in shared preference again.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize Shared Preference like below :

Suppose you are setting Login preference to true in LoginActivity.

When you are getting LOGIN set preference as below :

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    Editor editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putBoolean("isLogin",true);
    editoe.commit();
```

And you are setting Logout preference in LogoutActiviy.
And whenever you are getting Logout set preference as below :

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    Editor editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putBoolean("isLogin",false);
    editoe.commit();
```

And check your first page if user is Login or not like below :

```
if(pref.getBoolean("isLogin", false)){
      // Condtion gets true if you are login
}else{
      // Condtion gets false if you are not login
}
```

Hope it will help you.

For more reference you can also refer below link:

[Android login/registration with shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740185/android-login-registration-with-shared-preferences)

Comment: I want to use shared preference variable in  MainActivity.Java class.In my MainActivity, for my logout button I want to use :-
 else if(id ==R.id.nav_Logout){

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isLogin",false);
            editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                MainActivity.this.getIntent();
        }    But it is giving error in using sharedpreference.How can i use it in other java class?

Comment: You need to initialize preference with the same key as you have initialize while login. See my edits

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call these two methods on your Editor class object.

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

You can reply if you want further assistance. Good Luck.