# Displaying data using Shared Preferences

Tags: android-studio, android-sharedpreferences

I am currently doing a project that requires to show data in another activity.
I have created a RegisterActivity and I want some details from that page to be shown in the HomeActivity after the user has logged in(Meant for the specific user). So far, after I login, I am only able to see the Username and not other details.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please, consider providing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please refer the following link
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740185/android-login-registration-with-shared-preferences>

Comment: Please add your code snippet

Comment: Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remember we are not a free coding service ;)